# print one table of multi table in one page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php page with 3 or more tables.
I need to print them. I have a javascript code for print a table that works for a page with one table but if I have 2 or more tables and when I click on print button only the first table will be printed.
Can any body help me to print second or third table?
Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function printPage(){
    var tableData = '<table border="1" dir="rtl">'+document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML+'</table>';
    var data = '<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>'+tableData;
    myWindow=window.open('','','width=800,height=600');
    myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
    myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
    myWindow.screenX = 0;
    myWindow.screenY = 0;
    myWindow.document.write(data);
    myWindow.focus();
  };
</script>
```

and this is my print link code:

```
<a id="print" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="printPage();">print</a>
```

Comment: Have you done a for loop and then add them all together??

Comment: yes actually i have a while loop to get data from my database and put them to table(s)

Comment: That is good, but I mean that, in the printPage(), do a for loop and get the total number of tables and do all the operations for one table and append the results together?

Comment: yes i have it.i thugth if i give to my table different id's this problem maybe solve but i dont know how to tell my javascript code there is different id

Comment: I gave a solution, please check it out and see if it works.

Comment: no i'm afraid it not work!!

Comment: What is the console.log showing??

Comment: i dont know what is console log
whene i click on the link i get any reaction

Comment: If you are using chrome, then press Ctrl+Shift+C to open the console log of the browser... It displays various errors if they exist. Just click on the console tab in that and refresh the page and tell me if there is any error.

Comment: ok i did it and i get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Comment: OK you almost solve my problem but in this way i got all table to print, but i want to print just one of them

Comment: But the question asks, if there are more tables in the page, then print all 2nd and 3rd as well...?? So you want to select the table you want to print??

Comment: sorry it's my bad .sorry if i cant tell my point well

Comment: So what is it? select the table you want to print? or if by chance on a page you retrieve 2 tables, it will print both the tables?

Comment: i want to print one table that i choose from 3 table that i have in my page

Comment: But I think it is not possible to do it with one link, you would need three links and each one mapped to one table.... Is that what you looking for?

Comment: tnx i got my answer i created some links to print them off

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you get an idea. I have not tested it because I dont have any specific data to work on. But do check it out and see if it works.

```
function printPage(){
  var tableData = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('table').length; i++){
    tableData = tableData + '<table border="1" dir="rtl">'+document.getElementsByTagName('table')[i].innerHTML+'</table>';
  }
    var data = '<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>'+tableData;
    myWindow=window.open('','','width=800,height=600');
    myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
    myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
    myWindow.screenX = 0;
    myWindow.screenY = 0;
    myWindow.document.write(data);
    myWindow.focus();

}
```

This will append all the tables and will allow you to print all of them.

But if you want to select a table you want to print, then there are different ways to do it like, for example keeping 3 links which are connected with the 3 tables or bring up a window with a select option which chooses the table that you need. Either way, you can change the above functionality in such a way that you would pass a index value of the table to the `printPage()` function like this:

```
function printPage(t){
    tableData = '<table border="1" dir="rtl">'+document.getElementsByTagName('table')[t].innerHTML+'</table>';
    var data = '<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>'+tableData;
    myWindow=window.open('','','width=800,height=600');
    myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
    myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
    myWindow.screenX = 0;
    myWindow.screenY = 0;
    myWindow.document.write(data);
    myWindow.focus();

}
```

Here `t` is the index of the table you want to select, and it print the required table. Then you can proceed from there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok I have edited the answer, silly mistake(syntax error). Kindly check it out and see if it works.